# Discord.py issues with full YTDL playthrough

Tags: python, bots, discord, youtube-dl

I've been working on a discord bot in using discord.py, and I'm currently working on getting it to play youtube videos using YTDL. However no matter what song it is the bot stops playing the song, and then soon after crashes at about a minute into the song.

Current code:

[image]

Comment: You should include your code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the issue, the player functions in discord.py do not play well with traditional while loops. For anyone with the same issue replace your current while loop with one that looks like this

```
while not ytplayer.is_done():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
await my_bot.voice.disconnect()
```